# Automoderation system whitelist discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to whitelist some words with my auto moderation system for discord.js. Below is my code for the auto moderation in the message that works perfectly fine.

```
const censorlist = require(`./censorlist.json`);
if(censorList.autoModTrigger.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
    //code here
});
```

but I want to whitelist "hello" so I tried it like this:

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("hello")) return;
```

but with this code for example if you say "hello [blacklisted word]" it won't censor it so I want to fix that.

Comment: If you're whitelisting `hello` then even if you do blacklist the word that comes after it, your bot won't be able to detect it because you've already returned the message as okay.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I want to whitelist hello"? In my understanding whitelisting in that context would be ignoring a blacklisted word if the "hello" word is in the message content, which means it is working as intended.

Comment: I mean that if someone says like "hello [swear word]" it will still censor the message but if someone says "hello" it wont censor it cause currently it doesnt censor "hello [swear word]" cause it contains "hello"

Comment: could you please add how you have created your `censorlist.json` that would help me creating an appropriate answer for you since you would need to use `fs` and remove the word to whitelist it

Comment: censorlist.json is just like
`{
   autoModTrigger: ["word", "word"]
}`
but you dont have to remove the word from the censorlist, its just that in "hello" there is "hell" so "hell" shouldnt be whitelisted but "hello" should if you tought that was the problem

Comment: You can't use both strategies. Either you use an allowed list or a denied list. In an allowed list, only word in the list are acceptable and all others will be censored. In a deny list, all words are acceptable except those in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your question is a bit too opinion-based since you seem to still be on the decision making side of the development, and not about a specific problem.

But since I may be misinterpreting it, I might as well give you something.

You already have a blacklist that seem to (or should) be working, with this:

```
const censorlist = require(`./censorlist.json`);
if(censorList.autoModTrigger.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
  //code here
});
```

Since you are going to do basically the same with your whitelist, we're gonna move that to a function.

```
function doesIntersect(text, wordlist) {
  return wordlist.some(word => text.toLowerCase().includes(word))
}
```

So your previous code will look something like that:

```
const censorlist = require(`./censorlist.json`);
if (doesIntersect(message.content, censorList.autoModTrigger)) {
  // Code here
}
```

And now, you want to ignore the blacklist if your message contains a whitelisted word, so let's do just that!

```
const censorlist = require(`./censorlist.json`);
if (!doesIntersect(message.content, censorList.whitelist)
  && doesIntersect(message.content, censorList.autoModTrigger)) {
  // Code here
}
```

In that code I assume that your list of whitelisted words is in the `whitelist` property at the root of your "censorlist.json" file.

Side note: I could have made a boolean variable for each intersection result, but it's better to do it in the if condition so that lazy evaluation will ignore the right-hand of the `&&` if the left-hand is falsy.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and I think it will work. Currently I am trying with some help from others to make a var called newContent that will filter out all whitelisted words and replace it with nothing, after that it will check if there are any blacklisted words left in the newContent and do something. If I cant get that to work I will try yours. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

[Allow/deny lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelisting#Controversy) are two opposite approaches to the same problem. There's a list of things and some of those things need to be removed. You can either explicitly allow some of them and deny the rest (an allow or "white" list) or you can explicitly deny some of them and allow the rest (a deny or "black" list). Combining the two approaches makes no sense, because there will always be items that aren't in either list. How you treat those unlisted items determines which approach you are using.

Your problem is that you are matching **characters** instead of **words**. You've banned the **word** "hell", but it's matching the **characters** in the **word** "hello".

The solution is not to create an allow list including "hello", it's to fix your implementation.

While there are many possible approaches, one is to use a regex with word boundaries (often expressed as `\b`) to match whole words instead of just characters.

For example:

```js
"Hello, welcome to Hell.".replace(/\b(hell)\b/i, (word) => "*".repeat(word.length));
```

If you have a long list, you can use the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to concatenate a list together from your json file (just make sure to escape special characters, if there are any).

You can also try other approaches, like splitting the string on non-word characters (like spaces and punctuation) and searching for censored words that way.

However, just about any solution is going to let plenty of creative profanity through (see East Germany, circa 1980), so you have to decide how strict you want to be. If you want to catch the obvious stuff to prove you are trying, then the above solution or something similar should be sufficient. If you really want to get strict, then you are going to need an AI that understands human language or a team of humans reviewing and censoring all communications (see East Germany, circa 1980).

Comment: This is a question about Discord, there is no way to edit message sent by other users so there is no use in replacing words with other characters, just detection. Good thinking about the word boundaries, I forgot to use those in my answer.

Comment: Of course you cant edit someone else's message, im not trying to use that. I make a var of the content and replace whitelisted words in that var.